# Знатоки zed_graph (графики) с#

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                List[i] = new PointPairList();
                tmp = DataY[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < t.Length; j++)
                {
                    tmp[i] = DataY[i][j];
                    current_date = start_date.AddDays(j);
                    List[i].Add(new XDate(current_date), tmp[j]);
                }
                curve[i] = pane.AddCurve("", List[i], Color.FromArgb(255, R[i], G[i], B[i]), SymbolType.Circle);
                //List = null;
            }
```

Циклом я реализую, создание кривых curve (3 штуки).
Потом я добавляю их в pane. (Это объект класса GraphPane)
Как мне теперь удалять эти графики ?

удаляет вот так вот `curve[1].Clear();`

Но мне надо удалять их из другой функции (там событие по нажатию клавиши происходит). как такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 2):

Метод `Clear()` просто очищает точки у объекта кривой (`Curve`). Сам объект класса `Curve` остается в списке панели (`CurveList`), т.е. кривая никуда не удаляется, она просто пустая - не имеет точек.

Для удаления объета кривой нужно на списке кривых вызвать один из методов `Remove`/`RemoveAt`.
Например, вот так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CurveItem curve = GetCurve(); // Метод, который получает нужную кривую. Здесь Ваша логика.
    zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList.Remove(curve);
    zedGraph.Invalidate();
}
```